ReadTheDocs sphix build error: index.rst not found
I'm trying to build and publish documentation on ReadTheDocs from a github repo.
The build yields an error:
Running Sphinx v7.3.7
making output directory... done
WARNING: html_static_path entry '_static' does not exist
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
writing output... 
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 0 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/betterpathlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sphinx/cmd/build.py", line 337, in build_main
    app.build(args.force_all, args.filenames)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/betterpathlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 351, in build
    self.builder.build_update()
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/betterpathlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 293, in build_update
    self.build(to_build,
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/betterpathlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 313, in build
    updated_docnames = set(self.read())
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/betterpathlib/envs/latest/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 422, in read
    raise SphinxError('root file %s not found' %
sphinx.errors.SphinxError: root file /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/betterpathlib/checkouts/latest/docs/index.rst not found

Sphinx error:
root file /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/betterpathlib/checkouts/latest/docs/index.rst not found

I have the file .readthedocs.yaml at project root, with these lines:
...


# Build documentation in the "docs/" directory with Sphinx
sphinx:
  configuration: docs/conf.py

and in docs/conf.py:
# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#project-information

project = 'betterpathlib'
copyright = '2024, xx'
author = 'xx'

# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#general-configuration

extensions = []

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']

# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-html-output

html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_static_path = ['_static']


The error message makes sense since there is no index.rst in your repository: https://github.com/tsoernes/betterpathlib/tree/main/docs. There are two conf.py files on the other hand. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-root_doc

@mzjn I thought RTD would generate index.rst for me.

@tsorn not anymore. They recently changed their policy. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78393774/2214933
